# Counting nonzero elements with JAX and JIT

Tags: python, jit, jax

I'm trying to write a simple Monte Carlo estimation of pi using JAX and JIT, but keep running into a TracerIntegerConversionError. How are JIT functions supposed to be designed to get around this? Thanks in advance!

```
import numpy as np
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
import time

n = 10000

@jax.jit
def jax_mc(n):
  x = jnp.array(np.random.rand(n))
  y = jnp.array(np.random.rand(n))
  z = x**2 + y**2
  a = jnp.where(z <= 1, z,0)
  count = jnp.count_nonzero(a)
  return 4*count/n

start_np = time.time()
print(jax_mc(n))
end_np = time.time()
print(end_np-start_np)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues here.

First, array sizes must be static in JAX (for some discussion, see [JAX Sharp Bits: Dynamic Shapes](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#dynamic-shapes)) In your function `n` is dynamic, and so you cannot construct an array of shape `n` when the function is JIT-compiled.

Second, you're using `numpy.random` within a JIT-compiled function, which will most likely not behave as you expect. You should use `jax.random` instead; see [JAX Sharp Bits: Random Numbers](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#random-numbers) for more discussion of this.

Third, your timing is not taking into account JAX's asynchronous dispatch. Read [Benchmarking JAX Code](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#benchmarking-jax-code) for some discussion of considerations when running these kinds of benchmarks.

With these points in mind,
I would probably rewrite your code this way:

```py
from functools import partial
import numpy as np
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
import time

n = 10000

@partial(jax.jit, static_argnames=['n'])
def jax_mc(key, n):
  key1, key2 = jax.random.split(key)
  x = jax.random.normal(key1, shape=(n,))
  y = jax.random.normal(key2, shape=(n,))
  z = x**2 + y**2
  a = jnp.where(z <= 1, z,0)
  count = jnp.count_nonzero(a)
  return 4*count/n

key = jax.random.PRNGKey(0)
start = time.time()
_ = jax_mc(key, n)
end = time.time()
print('compilation time:', end - start)

start = time.time()
result = jax_mc(key, n).block_until_ready()
end = time.time()
print("runtime:", end - start)
print("result:", result)
```

```
compilation time: 0.8846290111541748
runtime: 0.0018401145935058594
result: 1.5516
```